# Dropdownlist error when dynamically generated?

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a dropdownlist called "ddlYears" dynamically like below code:

```
private void CreateDynamicDDL()  
{      
    ddlYears.Items.Clear();
    ddlYears.Items.Add(new ListItem("Year","0")); 
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)  
    {  
        int time = int.Parse(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());
        ddlYears.Items.Add(new ListItem((time-k).ToString(),(k+1).ToString()));    
    }
}
```

and I have ddl selectedindexchanged event as below:

```
protected void ddlYears_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{    
    Response.Write(ddlYears.SelectedValue.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

In the above code I am trying to write the selected value. But it's working fine, if select the second item which is "2010" (I mean returning selected value as 1) and so on, but if I select first item which is "Year" it's not firing that `ddlYears_SelectedIndexChanged` event. Please somebody help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have "Year" as the first item then by default it is already selected. If you drop down the list and re-select it, it won't call the SelectedIndexChanged method.

Does it work if you select 2010 and then select Year again?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
But if I select 2010 and then select "Year" back it's not working. It simply reloading the page and never fire the "ddlYears_SelectedIndexChanged event.

Thanks